# What's the difference between bounce_queue_lifetime & maximal_queue_lifetime in postfix?

Tags: postfix

Based on postfix official manual,
 [bounce_queue_lifetime](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#)

> Consider a bounce message as undeliverable, when delivery fails with a
>   temporary error, and the time in the queue has reached the
>   bounce_queue_lifetime limit. By default, this limit is the same as for
>   regular mail.

[maximal_queue_lifetime](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#)

> Consider a message as undeliverable, when delivery fails with a
>   temporary error, and the time in the queue has reached the
>   maximal_queue_lifetime limit.

Since I got warning as:`postfix/qmgr[10221]: warning: bounce_queue_lifetime is larger than maximal_queue_lifetime - adjusting bounce_queue_lifetime`.

I want to know what's the difference between bounce_queue_lifetime & maximal_queue_lifetime

Answer (score 1):

I found another explanation http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html

`maximal_queue_lifetime` (default: 5 days)
How long a message stays in the queue before it is sent back as undeliverable. Specify 0 for mail that should be returned immediately after the first unsuccessful delivery attempt.

`bounce_queue_lifetime` (default: 5 days, available with Postfix version 2.1 and later)
How long a MAILER-DAEMON message stays in the queue before it is considered undeliverable. Specify 0 for mail that should be tried only once.